# making lists from data in a file in python

Tags: python, file, list, python-2.7

I'm really new at python and needed help in making a list from data in a file. The list contains numbers on separate lines (by use of "\n" and this is something I don't want to change to CSV). The amount of numbers saved can be changed at any time because the way the data is saved to the file is as follows:

Program 1:

```
        # creates a new file for writing
numbersFile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
    # determines how many times the loop will iterate
totalNumbers = input("How many numbers would you like to save in the file? ")
    # loop to get numbers
count = 0
while count < totalNumbers:
    number = input("Enter a number: ")
        # writes number to file
    numbersFile.write(str(number) + "\n")
    count = count + 1
```

This is the second program that uses that data. This is the part that is messy and that I'm unsure of:

Program 2:

```
maxNumbers = input("How many numbers are in the file? ")
numFile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

total = 0
count = 0
while count < maxNumbers:
    total = total + numbers[count]
    count = count + 1
```

I want to use the data gathered from program 1 to get a total in program 2. I wanted to put it in a list because the amount of numbers can vary. This is for an introduction to computer programming class, so I need a SIMPLE fix. Thank you to all who help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first program is fine, although you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` (which also makes it unnecessary to call `str()` on the result).

Your second program has a small problem: You're not actually reading anything from the file. Fortunately, that's easy in Python. You can iterate over the lines in a file using

```
for line in numFile:
    # line now contains the current line, including a trailing \n, if present
```

so you don't need to ask for the total of numbers in your file at all.

If you want to add the numbers, don't forget to convert the string `line` to an `int` first:

```
total += int(line)       # shorthand for total = total + int(line)
```

There remains one problem (thanks @tobias_k!): The last line of the file will be empty, and `int("")` raises an error, so you could check that first:

```
for line in numFile:
    if line:
        total += int(line)
```

Comment: Watch out for empty last line! `int('')` will produce an error.

Comment: This might seem ridiculously dumb, but... what is the "for line in numFile:" for... Where do I use that? The way I set it up, I wanted to ask the user how many numbers they had in the file, using that to determine how many times the loop will iterate. And with each iteration, it would add the number on a line to the total.

Comment: Why do you want to ask the user that? What if he's wrong? The `for` loop will take one line from the file at a time and stop when the last line has been read.

Comment: My professor wants us to use programs that don't have a limit on how many items are in a list. ("Programs should work with input files with any number of lines." <-- his words exactly) So I didn't know how else to go about adding the total in the second program without using a loop and thus asking the user how many items are in the file. Not that there is a user. Most of the examples are quite unrealistic.

Comment: And I just saw your edited post, thank you for answering my question and thank you tobias for that edit. If I wanted to get an average of all the numbers in the file, how would I check how many numbers are in the file without asking the user?

Comment: @bij0ux: You can count them as you go along, or use `for index, line in enumerate(numFile):` - then `index` counts the lines for you. Be careful, the index of the first line is `0` - but since you have an empty line at the end of the file, the final value of `index` will contain the number of values in your file.